# How to make a new Tag?

Tags: feature-request, support

How can I make a new Tag on Puzzling Beta ?

I was doing some Knights and Knave Puzzles by [Smullyan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan) and was slightly disappointed that there was no tag to differentiate these puzzles from the others ...

Comment: You can't make it. You need at least 150 reputation.

Comment: Thanks @CoolGuy - Also I have deleted the post on Puzzling Beta . I did not know which was the more appropriate place to post the question : Puzzling Beta or Meta :) Thanks a ton ...

Comment: Read [What's meta? How does it work?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) to know more.

Comment: Thanks again @CoolGuy , I hope my offence is not serious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually *is* a tag for this: the [liars](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liars) tag, now synonymised with the [knights-and-knaves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-and-knaves) tag. This is the tag to use for your questions.

Comment: And now someone needs to go and edit that tag back in to all the questions that need it. Volunteers?

Comment: There is already a [liars] tag for knights and knaves puzzles.  Use that one instead?

Comment: @McMagister At my request, the esteemed Doorknoob has synonymised [liars] and [knights-and-knaves].

Answer (score 1):

As informed by @CoolGuy in the comments , One can only make tags only if you have a reputation of at least 150